# Show that abelianization is the left adjoint of forgetful functor from abelian groups to groups.

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to show that the left adjoint of forgetful functor from abelian groups to groups is the abelianization. 
After a while of thinking, I think it amounts to showing that the abelinization of a group $G$ satiefies the universal property that every map from $G$ to an abelian group $H_{\mathrm{ab}}$ factor through the quotient of $G$ mod the commutators.

Is that sufficient? Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Yep, exactly right. This is exactly what you get when you unpack the definition of the adjoint-ness of the functors. Although if you want to be super precise, you should actually define the bijections between the Hom sets and explicitly check naturality of these bijections in all the variables.

Comment: @AshwinIyengar Defining the bijections between hom-sets and checking naturality is **one** way to prove adjointness. What the OP proposes is sufficient as it is (except that he/she forgot "uniquely" after "factors"). To be more precise, $U:D \to C$ admits a left adjoint whenever each $G \downarrow U$ as a initial object for $G\in C$.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, I guess it depends on what definition you take